# sns.regplot does not show the fitted regression line

Tags: python, csv, seaborn

I am new to Python and have a problem that I want to solve.

I used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

path='https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DA0101EN/automobileEDA.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)

sns.regplot(x="engine-size", y="price", data=df)
plt.ylim(0,)
```

When I run the code the I don't get the fitted regression line, only the Scatterplot shows up. 
I also get following error:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Can someone help?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works fine for me with seaborn v.0.10.0 and pandas v.0.25.3

Comment: Probably it is [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060301/typeerror-cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypeint64-to-dtypeint32-accordin/60243061#60243061): a bug in seaborn when running with a 32-bit numpy library.