# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe' while plotting

Tags: python, seaborn

> I am trying to plot the number of survived people in regards to their sex (titanic data set) and I am getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'`. I know that the column `Sex` has values of categorical type (female, male) but I do not wish to convert them into 0 or 1, respectively. Is there any way to **correctly** plot these two columns (`Sex`, `Survived`)?

**What I have tried:**

1. `ax = sns.barplot(x = 'Sex', y = 'Survived', data = train, order = ['female', 'male'])`
2. `ax = sns.barplot(x = 'Sex', y = 'Survived', data = train)`
3. `ax = sns.barplot(x = np.array(train['Sex']), y = 'Survived', data = train, order = ['female', 'male'])`
4. `ax = sns.barplot(x = np.array(train['Sex']), y = 'Survived', data = train)`
5. Changing the data types of all the columns from `int64` to `int32` with the following code:

```py
convert_dict = {'PassengerId' : int,
                'Pclass' : int,
                'SibSp' : int,
                'Parch' : int,
                'Survived' : int}  
train = train.astype(convert_dict)
```

**Error dialogue:**

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-313-39c697b1f1c5> in <module>
----> 1 ax = sns.barplot(x = 'Sex', y = 'Survived', data = train)

c:\users\userpc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in barplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, orient, color, palette, saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge, ax, **kwargs)
   3148                           estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed,
   3149                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
-> 3150                           errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
   3151 
   3152     if ax is None:

c:\users\userpc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, orient, color, palette, saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
   1615                                  order, hue_order, units)
   1616         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
-> 1617         self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot, seed)
   1618 
   1619         self.dodge = dodge

c:\users\userpc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in estimate_statistic(self, estimator, ci, n_boot, seed)
   1517                                           n_boot=n_boot,
   1518                                           units=unit_data,
-> 1519                                           seed=seed)
   1520                         confint.append(utils.ci(boots, ci))
   1521 

c:\users\userpc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\algorithms.py in bootstrap(*args, **kwargs)
     83     for i in range(int(n_boot)):
     84         resampler = integers(0, n, n)
---> 85         sample = [a.take(resampler, axis=0) for a in args]
     86         boot_dist.append(f(*sample, **func_kwargs))
     87     return np.array(boot_dist)

c:\users\userpc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\algorithms.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     83     for i in range(int(n_boot)):
     84         resampler = integers(0, n, n)
---> 85         sample = [a.take(resampler, axis=0) for a in args]
     86         boot_dist.append(f(*sample, **func_kwargs))
     87     return np.array(boot_dist)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: Seems your data has dtype = int64 and plot needs int32, but the plot function cant cast this because doing it can lost your data and plot wrong information. So, try to do data = np.asarray(train, dtype=np.int32)

Comment: @AugustoMaillo I tried what you suggested and I got this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'`. I suppose `np.asarray` converts all the data types from whatever they are to whatever you specify. In this case, there are some columns with the data type `object`. Is there any way that I can change the data types of specific columns from `int64` to `int32`?

Comment: I would need to see exactly what you want to do to help you. The solution depends your data organization. If you are trying to plot just numbers, filter _train_ before pass it to plot.

Comment: Your crash is in the same 'algorithms.py'  as [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060301/typeerror-cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypeint64-to-dtypeint32-accordin/60243061#60243061) in seaborn. Related to running a 32 bit version of numpy. The bug should be solved now with the newest seaborn 0.10.1